# Why do I get an uninitialized constant 'Controller'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /bankacct/new

uninitialized constant BankacctController
```

I feel like this error is because I named something wrong. Any ideas?

bankaccts_controller.rb:

```
class BankacctsController < ApplicationController

  def new 
  end

  def create
    # some code
  end

end
```

app/views/bankaccts/new.html.haml:

```
%form
  = label_tag :bank_name, "Account Holder's Name"
  = text_field_tag :bank_name, nil, name: nil, :value => "John Q. TaxPayer", class: "ba-name"
  %br
  = label_tag :acct_num, "Account Number"
  = text_field_tag :acct_num, nil, name: nil, :value => "9900000001", class: "ba-an"
  %p
  %button{:type => "submit"}
    tokenize
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :bankacct
```

rake routes:

```
bankacct_index GET   /bankacct(.:format)          bankacct#index
               POST  /bankacct(.:format)          bankacct#create
  new_bankacct GET   /bankacct/new(.:format)      bankacct#new
 edit_bankacct GET   /bankacct/:id/edit(.:format) bankacct#edit
      bankacct GET   /bankacct/:id(.:format)      bankacct#show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

routes.rb should have:

`resources :bankaccts`

Comment: I'll mark you correct in a second it makes me wait 5 minutes before doing it. :/

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be `resources :bankaccts`.